# jquery json object

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jquery json object like:

```
{"meta":{"limit":20,"next":null,"offset":0,"previous":null,"total_count":2},
"objects":[
{"body":"Body 1","date":"2013-01-15},
{"body":"Body 2","date":"2013-02-25}
 ]}
```

I would like to  display looped data:

```
body 1, date
body 2, date
```

Comment: could you maybe provide the HTML that you would like to display this information?  have you thought of using a templating plugin?

Comment: What the hell is a *jQuery*-JSON object? :P

Comment: Also your json is invalid you need to close your date with " otherwise nothing will work ie "date":"2013-01-15"

Comment: You can try like this objects[0]["body"]  hope it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var data= "yourjson";
$.each(data.objects,function(i,v){ 
    alert(v.body);
      alert(v.date);
});
```

had to correct some of the issues in the json.. like missing `"`... so please check the fiddle.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/UCUJY/)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your JSON is invalid. You lack parentheses after date. This is a valid JSON:

```
var json = {"meta":{"limit":20,"next":null,"offset":0,"previous":null,"total_count":2},
"objects":[
{"body":"Body 1","date":"2013-01-15"},
{"body":"Body 2","date":"2013-02-25"}
]};
```

Please note the " sign after '2013-01-15' and after '2013-02-25'.

You can display 'body' and 'date' using [JQuery's .each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each(json.objects, function (index, obj) {
  console.log(obj.body + " " + obj.date);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your json first as it is invalid as your not closing your date with "

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 2
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "body": "Body 1",
            "date": "2013-01-15"
        },
        {
            "body": "Body2",
            "date": "2013-02-25"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then something like this should work

```
  $.each(data.objects[0],function(i,v){ 
        alert(v.body+" - "+v.date);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {"meta":{"limit":20,"next":null,"offset":0,"previous":null,"total_count":2},
    "objects":[
        {"body":"Body 1","date":"2013-01-15"},
        {"body":"Body 2","date":"2013-02-25"}
 ]};

for(var i = 0; i < data.objects.length; i++){
    alert(data.objects[i].body);
    alert(data.objects[i].date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects are like key-value pairs.

Suppose this whole JSON object is in variable `data` then to read the content, do the following.

`meta` is an `object` containing different data, so to read `limit`, `next` and others you have to use `data.meta.limit` and so on.

Now `objects` is `array` type in which there are different objects.

So to read `body`, execute `data.objects[0].body` and so on.